# Rails: Confused how tutorial is able to call line items object within method

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm working through the book Agile Web Development 6th ed. In Task G, I am confused how `line_items` is able to be called from the `add_line_items_from_cart` method. The code is as follows:

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :line_items, dependent: :destroy

  def add_line_items_from_cart(cart)
    cart.line_items.each do |item|
      item.cart_id = nil
      line_items << item
    end
  end

class LineItem < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :order, optional: true
  ...
end
```

I fired up a rails console and when I run

```
c = Cart.last
c.line_items.each do |item|
  item.id
  line_items
end
```

I get
`NameError (undefined local variable or method 'line_items' for main:Object)`

Why is `line_items` able to work in the method above, without prepending `c.line_items`? And why doesn't it work when I run it in rails console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`line_items` in the method will be executed as

`self.line_items << item`

here `self` will be referring to the instance of `Order` class

but in case of calling it from rails console it will try to find a local variable `line_items` that's why you are getting an error